# controller access in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In order to access a controller, why do I have to type `index.php/ControllerName` to access that controller. Why cant I specify the controller name directly from the base url? like so`/ControllerName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

By default, the index.php file will is included in your URLs but you can remove it using this method.

Comment: where do i put the htaccess file

Comment: Codeigniter should have one already but put it on the root of your site. Save it as .htaccess - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: i have put htaccess file there in /application directory but same problem occurs

Comment: Not the application directory. The very root of your site eg. /.htaccess

Comment: i have fix problem by updating Re Write base option.

Answer (score 0):

You should create in www folder .htacces file and add such rules there

```
   DirectoryIndex index.php

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
   </IfModule>
```